# simple-scan Ubuntu 22.04 : error message while saving file - ghost process

Tags: scanner, process, filemanager

since I am using Ubuntu 22.04, simple-scan shows this error message when saving the scanned page :

> Failed to execute child process " " (No such file or directory).

It really saves the file,actually, but simple-scan does not get the info and then gives an alert if you want to leave the application.

Other application have the same behaviour. It seems related to Nautilus, but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In preferences, try unchecking 'postprocessing' if you have it selected. I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well.  I don't remember setting it, and I don't remember ever having this problem in the past with the exact same scanner and simplescan.  Love simple-scan.

Comment: Also worked for me, although the switch did not change until I exited and restarted simplescan. The null entries for "script" and "script arguments" did disappear. Maybe the issue is not having passed a script.

Comment: Worked for me as well, I do remember enabling  postprocessing though. And now it makes sense. There is no postprocessing on board, you need to pass the script which does it. Leaving that empty it tries to execute the script at the empty path which fails.

Comment: Linked this question in the according [bug on the project page](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan/-/issues/363).